# Creating a Package with files using Swift package manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a project with structure

Package 1
file 11
file 12
folder
file 13

Package 2
file 21
file 22
folder
file 23

package 1 and 2 are in same folder. Now I want to create a Package 3 using
file 12
file 13
file 23

is it possible in swift package manager to create package 3 with out disturbing package1 and package2 structure?.

Comment: It should be possible but you don't want to do it. Having two copies of the same file in different packages will only lead to confusion and you would always has to update the code in two places when you change anything. Maybe this is an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) so maybe you could explain why you are asking about this?

Comment: I want to create package specifying by files which are located in different folders and is there any way I can do? Path specifies folder but I don't see option for specifying files location

Comment: No, you need to add the files under the Sources folder but apart from the target folder(s) you can also create any sub folder within a target folder.